# In postgres unable to create database

Tags: postgresql, psql

I installed the package using:
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev

but in postgresql mode:
it was not creating database
I am using ubuntu 22.04

I waited for an hour still it was running, I don't know why it was not creating database but it was executing alter statement

Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

[image: this is the image]

Comment: Is there anything interesting in the Postgres error log?

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is blocked by a lock. Most likely, somebody is connected to the `template1` database. Terminate that database session, and the `CREATE DATABASE` statement should proceed.